# Do APIs need to hash data or is that done before/after the API call?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api

I am creating an API for a class this semester and I know that all of the data we are storing we need to hash for security reasons. I was wondering if the hashing was done by the API?

Comment: By _hash_, do you mean _one-way hashing_ or do you just mean _encrypt_?

Comment: I believe just one-way hash, but would it make a difference is it was encrypt?

Comment: I was just wondering that if you were to hash data before an API call, then how would the server know what data was hashed?

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by API? WebApi? A DLL library API? A WCF API? An XML WebService API? A .NET Remoting API? Please add more details of the scenario to your question.

Comment: I mean a web API. And Mark, that is essentially my question